# Reduction from knapsack problem to Integer relation that equals one

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-hard, number-theory, knapsack-problems

My question is related to the [Integer Relation Detection Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) which can be formulated as:

$\qquad a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = 0$

Where $\forall i. a_i\in\mathbb{Z} \land a_i<c \land x\in \mathbb{R}$, and $\exists i. a_i\neq 0$. $c$ and vector $\mathbf{x}$ are given, and the problem is to find a valid vector $\mathbf{a}$ that satisfies these constraints.

There are a few algorithms to solve this problem, listed on the wikipedia page linked.

My question: are there algorithms for a solution to the same problem with the modification that

$\qquad a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = 1$?

Or equivalently (I believe),

$\qquad a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b$?

The constant $b\in \mathbb R$ is a given.

On [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191545/integer-relation-that-equals-one) I ask for a polynomial time algorithm or proof that none exist, with not much luck. Here I ask if a solution to this is equivalent to a solution the knapsack problem (can the knapsack problem be reduced to this), and this would thus be NP-hard.

Comment: Compute the GCD, if it divides $b$ then then is a solution. If $b$ is not an integer then there is no solution since integers are closed under linear addition and multiplication (putting aside the issue of how to represent a real number which is an infinitary object on a computer). The problem easily reduces to the case that $b=1$.

Comment: @Kaveh Is that a full answer?

Comment: @Raphael, no, I haven't explained how to find the coefficients for the linear combination of the numbers resulting in 1 when their GCD is 1 (I think it is quite standard topic in algorithmic number theory books).

Comment: I think Kaveh's answer is correct if $c=\infty$, but if we are given a finite $c$, then his answer won't necessarily work: the question says all of the $a_i$'s must be bounded above by $c$, where $c$ is supplied in the input.  The standard Euclidean algorithm approach (that Kaveh mentions) might yield large numbers for the $a_i$'s.  So, it looks like this question is still open, if we need to find a solution $a_1,\dots,a_n$ where $a_i < c$ for all $i$.